# Cambiar interprete en python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Tengo instalado python 3.7.6 y spyder 4.0.1, sin embargo, necesito compilar un código que fue escrito en python 2.6, así que  instalé python 2.6.6 para intentar compilar el código y seguí las instrucciones de "Hossein Rahimi" en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder#:%7E:text=You%20can%20launch%20the%20correct,check%20the%20results%20right%20away).  Sin embargo, al momento de crear un nuevo "environment" no aparece la opción de python 2.6, solo aparece disponible python 2.7.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna recomendación o alternativa para compilar el código de python 2.6?

**Información extra**

Este es el [código](https://github.com/carlosandrepaes/GaPP/blob/master/README.md) que necesito compilar.

Comment: Una alternativa es compilarlo desde un `virtualenv` de paso si tienes algun fallo o problema por alguna libreria instalada u otra cosa no tienes que preocuparte ya que estas en un entorno virtual , te dejo un enlace  para que lo veas mejor:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: Por lo que veo en la imagen, usas anaconda (deberías ponerlo en las etiquetas). Anaconda/Miniconda no soportan las versiones inferiores a python 2.7, por lo que tendrás que construir el entorno con `virtualenv` descargando python-2.6 desde la web. ¿Has tenido problemas con python 2.7?

Comment: Logré compilar el código utilizando python 2.7.5 Gracias por la recomendación.